# read and write jpeg without ImageIO

Tags: java

how can i read jpeg image from byte[] and write to file? i cannot use `ImageIO` , `Bitmap` and `Bitmapfactory`

i want pure java solution , so that it works in android as well 
the lib i am creating is separate from android project but will be used with android  and as well as desktop application so a pure java solution is needed

the task is simple just read byte[] and save it to a file , for that i do not want to use a lib like a openCV

Comment: *"the task is simple"* If that is the case, then why is there a question here?

Comment: what i meant was , i need only this functionality, and for that i do not want to use lib like OpenCV or JAI

Comment: Just forget that it's a JPEG and read and write it like any other binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as with any binary file, this should do it:

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    out.write(bytes);
}
```